# Read/Write NumPy Structured Array very slow, linear in size slow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

To my surprise I have discovered, that reading from and writing to NumPy Structured arrays seems to be linear in size of the array.

As this seems very wrong, I would like to know, if I do something wrong here or if there might be a bug.

Here is some example code:

```
def test():
    A = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('a', np.int16), ('b', np.int16, (1,100))])
    B = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('a', np.int16), ('b', np.int16, (1,10000))])

    C = [{'a':0, 'b':[0 for i in xrange(100)]}]
    D = [{'a':0, 'b':[0 for i in xrange(10000)]}]

    for i in range(100):
        A[0]['a'] = 1
        B[0]['a'] = 1

        B['a'][0] = 1 
        x = A[0]['a']
        x = B[0]['a']

        C[0]['a'] = 1
        D[0]['a'] = 1
```

Line Profiling gives the following results:

```
Total time: 5.28901 s,    Timer unit: 1e-06 s
Function: test at line 454


Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   454                                           @profile
   455                                           def test():
   456                                              
   457         1           10     10.0      0.0     A = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('a', np.int16), ('b', np.int16, (1,100))])
   458         1           13     13.0      0.0     B = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('a', np.int16), ('b', np.int16, (1,10000))])
   459                                           
   460       101           39      0.4      0.0     C = [{'a':0, 'b':[0 for i in xrange(100)]}]
   461     10001         3496      0.3      0.1     D = [{'a':0, 'b':[0 for i in xrange(10000)]}]
   462                                           
   463       101           54      0.5      0.0     for i in range(100):
   464       100        20739    207.4      0.4         A[0]['a'] = 1
   465       100      1741699  17417.0     32.9         B[0]['a'] = 1
   466                                                  
   467       100      1742374  17423.7     32.9         B['a'][0] = 1 
   468       100        20750    207.5      0.4         x = A[0]['a']
   469       100      1759634  17596.3     33.3         x = B[0]['a']
   470                                           
   471       100          123      1.2      0.0         C[0]['a'] = 1
   472       100           76      0.8      0.0         D[0]['a'] = 1
```

As you can see, I don't even access the larger array (although a size of 10.000 is actually really tiny..). BTW: Same behavior for shape=(10000,1) instead of (1,10000).

Any Ideas?

Interpreting a structured array as a list of dicts, and comparing to built-in functions, there is the expected computational cost independent of size (see C and D)

NumPy Ver. 1.10.1.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results on 1.8.1. Maybe it's a bug introduced since then, or they changed the semantics or something.

Comment: @user2357112 Following your answer I updated to NumPy 1.11.0 and checked again. Now everything runs like a charm. So there probably was a bug. If you post as an answer I can mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6739) with structured arrays on NumPy 1.10.1. The conversation in the issue log seems to indicate it's fixed on all more recent NumPy versions, including 1.10.2 and 1.11.0.

Updating NumPy should make the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

With `timeit` in `ipython` I get essentially the same times for `A` and `B`

```
In [30]: timeit A[0]['a']=1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 µs per loop

In [31]: timeit B[0]['a']=1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 µs per loop

In [32]: timeit B['a'][0]=1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 554 ns per loop

In [33]: timeit x=A[0]['a']
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 µs per loop

In [34]: timeit x=B[0]['a']
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 µs per loop
```

Even if I create `B` with a 100 records, times don't change

```
In [39]: timeit B['a']=1   # set 100 values at once
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 µs per loop

In [40]: timeit B['a'][10]=1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 540 ns per loop

In [41]: B.shape   # 2Mb size
Out[41]: (100,)
```

Even setting a 10000 values of the 'b' field isn't expensive

```
In [46]: B['b'].shape
Out[46]: (100, 1, 10000)

In [47]: B['b'][:,:,:100]=1

In [48]: timeit B['b'][:,:,:100]=1
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop

In [49]: B['b'].sum()
Out[49]: 10000

In [50]: np.__version__
Out[50]: '1.11.0'
```